# Syncronization of cache in Composite C1 in Load Balanced Environment

Tags: caching, c1-cms

I have searched for troubleshooting on syncronizing the cache items in a load balanced environment. Our setup consists of two frontend servers and Composite content is stored in a SQL server. When items are updated in the console both servers i.e. cache on both servers must  be updated. 
As far as I can see there is no composite package that can help with this syncronization. So this means that I must implement functionality that updates the cache on both servers if new data has been persisted.

http://api.composite.net/?topic=html/T_Composite_Data_DataEvents_1.htm describe events  DataEvents_OnBeforeAdd and DataEvents_OnStoreChanged. Will this be the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest you take a look at this thread https://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/279643. It contains some example source code and implementation advice on going down the path of manually purging the cache of other nodes.

Comment: Hi Magnus - I have done some testing and it appears that composite out of the box does something with the cache on all servers when I update content via the console on one of the servers. However there is a challenge with the media archive when CRUD'ing files. This only (obviously) only happens on the server that the console runs.

Comment: How does that work? any configuration to set that up? The nodes must somehow know of each other.
If the nodes are all connected to a file share, then maybe you can make symbolic links from the media folder to the file share.

Comment: Regarding other content fx. pages it just works. I haven't changed any configuration. Regaring media content: Simply by changing the rootDirectory to a UNC path under DataProviderPlugins <add rootDirectory="\\yourshare" storeId="MediaArchive"....